# Combining two Select statements with added formatting

Tags: t-sql, coldfusion

I have two Select Statements that return the correct information.

```
PartQnty = (Select SUM(Part_Qnty) from ClaimParts where claim_ID = Claims.Claim_ID),
```

and

```
PartCount = (Select count(parts_ID) from ClaimParts where claim_ID = Claims.Claim_ID),
```

I need to Combine the result of both in this format: "PartCount/PartQnty" (2/1)
It needs to be in the format above before being returned to the cfgridcolumn.

Comment: What version of SQL and can you provide more of the query? A sum() subquery like this can usually be refactored to be significantly more efficient and speed your application a good bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was to convert partqnty statement and partcount statement to varchars and add a "/" inbetween them.

```
convert(varchar(10),(Select count(parts_ID) from ClaimParts where claim_ID = Claims.Claim_ID))+'/'+convert(varchar(10),(Select SUM(Part_Qnty) from ClaimParts where claim_ID = Claims.Claim_ID)) AS lvq,
```

Comment: Are you looking for the number result of division of the two numbers or the text representation of the two numbers? ie 3 vs "6/2"

Comment: @Shawn I was looking for the text representation of the two numbers "6/2"

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started

```
select partQnty = sum(part_qnty)
, partCount = count(parts_id)
from claimParts cp join claims c on cp.claim_id = c.claims_id
```